No of samples, average, min, max and percentiles(90th, 95th, 99th) are not showing correctly on html report after test execution
No of samples, average, min, max and percentiles(90th, 95th, 99th) are not showing correctly on html report after test execution. Test configurations are as below.
Test plan written view
Ultimate thread group configurations
HTML Report View
Test plan view
I am expecting to see the exact number of samplers, average, min, max and percentile(90th,95th, 99th) correctly that were executed within the defined configuration under ultimate thread group while running tests from cmd.
By looking into .jtl file i came to know that there were multiple records exists for each transaction controller. Unable to understand how it is generating.

JMeter.s .jtl results file contains a separate record for each Sample Result

number of samplers is the number of lines in the .jtl results file minus header
average is arithmetic mean of samplers response times
min is minimum response time for a Sampler with a particular name (label)
max is maximum response time for a Sampler with a particular name (label)
percentile(90th,95th, 99th) are statistical measures showing the value where 90%, 95% or 99%  of Sample Results fall

More information:

JMeter Glossary
Analyzing JMeter Test Results Using JMeter Aggregate Report Listener

